# Unable to Store from datagridview Cells 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Tags: c#

I am just trying to store a datgridview's cell value into a decimal variable but i get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

```cs
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < dataGridView3.Rows.Count-1; y++)
        {
            if (dataGridView3.Rows[y].Cells[0].Value == dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value)
            {
                **decimal AA = (decimal)dataGridView3.Rows[y].Cells[3].Value;**
                AA = AA + (decimal)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;
                dataGridView3.Rows[y].Cells[3].Value = AA;
            }
        }
    }
    dataGridView3.Refresh();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg0vV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnLRa.png)

I am trying to sum the QtytoShip as the PartNumber is the same.

Comment: so sorry i cannot seems to get the post done in a correct format, but to be specific, when i compile, i get a error: System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

@ the line: decimal AA = (decimal)dataGridView3.Rows[y].Cells[3].Value;

Comment: If the type in the cell is a string you cannot cast to a double.  Instead use parse : decimal AA = Decimal.Parse(dataGridView3.Rows[y].Cells[3].Value).  Casting you can only cast one number type to a different number type.

Comment: Hi jdweng, Its a decimal, when i mouse over the value i can see 9.000000. I manage to resolve the issue by using Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView3.Rows[y].Cells[3].Value); instead of the (decimal)

Comment: ConvertToDecimal has 18 overloads include number types, string, character array.  A cast will not work with string or char[].

Answer (score 0):

You can only cast to `decimal` if you added the value as `decimal` into the cell and not as `string` or `double`, for instance.

If you added it as `double` you must first cast the `Value` returned as `object` to `double` to unbox it and then only you can cast it to `decimal`:

```cs
(decimal)(double)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value
```

But it is more likely that you added it as string, in which case you must parse this string to get a `decimal`. My advice is to add it as `decimal` in the first place and not to convert it string. If you did it to format it, the see this article: [How to: Format Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-format-data-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

There is also a bug. Comparing two values of type `object` (that's what the `Value` property returns) with `==` does a reference comparison. Therefore, even if the two invoices are the same, this might return `false`.

Solutions

- Cast to string first: `(string)value1) == (string)value2`   or
- Use `Equals` which calls the string objects `Equals` method: `value1.Equals(value)`.

You can also simplify the code by using `foreach` and by introducing variables:

```cs
// Assuming the quantities have been added as `string`
foreach (DataGridViewRow row1 in dataGridView1.Rows) {
    object invoice1 = row1.Cells[0].Value;
    decimal quantity1 = Decimal.Parse((string)row1.Cells[3].Value);
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row2 in dataGridView3.Rows) {
        object invoice2 = row2.Cells[0].Value;
        if (invoice1.Equals(invoice2)) {
            var cell2 = row2.Cells[3];
            decimal quantity2 = Decimal.Parse((string)cell2.Value);
            cell2.Value = quantity1 + quantity2;
        }
    }
}
dataGridView3.Refresh();
```

Since the values form the outer loop do not change while executing the inner loop, we can retrieve and convert the values before the inner loop for more efficiency.

---

A better way to work with DataGridViews is to use binding. See [How to: Bind Objects to Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-objects-to-windows-forms-datagridview-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Basically this boils down to create classes for you data and bind them to the controls. Then you can work on these data models instead of struggling with DataGridViewRows and DataGridViewCells.

```cs
public class InvoiceItem
{
    public string InvoiceId { get;set; }
    public string PartNo { get;set; }
    public string CustomerPartNo { get;set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get;set; }
}
```

Getting and adding items:

```cs
var items1 = new List<InvoiceItem>();
items1.Add(invoiceItem1);
items1.Add(invoiceItem2);
...

var items2 = new List<InvoiceItem>();
items1.Add(invoiceItemX);
items1.Add(invoiceItemY);
...

// If correctly wired up, this fills the datagridviews.
// You don't need to add row columns and cells manually.
bindingSource1.DataSource = items1;
bindingSource2.DataSource = items2;
```

Then the code then becomes much easier to write and read:

```cs
foreach (InvoiceItem item1 in items1) {
    foreach (InvoiceItem item2 in items2) {
        if (item1.InvoiceId == item2.InvoiceId) {
            item2.Quantity += item1.Quantity;
        }
    }
}
dataGridView3.Refresh();
```

Note that since class objects are of reference type, you don't need to replace them in the list or in the DataGridView.

And of course I encourage you to find better names than `items1`, `items2` etc. Since you know what they represent, you can choose better names than me.